# How to reset the value of a dropdown, On clicking of the label in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
value: 'Select (mm)',
```

```html
<div class="thickness-productlist" @click="value = 'Select (mm)'">
  CLEAR
</div>

<div class="aselect" :data-value="value" :data-list="list">
  
      <!-- <option selected value="0">{{ value }}</option> -->
      <option v-for="(item,i) in thickness" :key="i">
        {{ item }}
      </option>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

How to clear the value of a dropdown, On clicking of the label in Vuejs

Comment: Try to call a function by passing item into it and in the function reset your things. It's very ambiguous to use  `@click="value = 'Select (mm)'"`

Comment: @click="reset" and reset(){ //here what reference need to call }

Can u please check is that the right way

Answer (score 0):

the select is using a v-model
to clear your selected Value set the v-model to '' or Null

Comment: Basically from the option need to select the item or value and need to reset... Tried changing the v-model doesnt work